# Can't access classes in the jar file imported with Maven

Tags: java, maven, class, import, jar

I'm new to maven and I'm struggling importing classes from an imported external jar.
I imported the jar file with a Maven dependency (and added it in the lib directory of my project) but I still can't use the classes contained in it.

In my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>uk.ac.ox.cs.vada</groupId>
            <artifactId>VadaEngine</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/VadaEngine-1.16.6.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn clean install` it builds with no problem, but if I try to import a class contained in the jar:

[new Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbrGP.jpg)

[Suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wzc1u.jpg)

Clicking on the suggestion does not add the import, while adding it by my self:

[Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVjR6.jpg)

How can I solve this?

Comment: I already tried adding the jar as a project dependency but Maven automatically deletes it.
Btw I also set the classpath to the jar in my .zprofile file with 'export CLASSPATH=".:usr/local/lib/VadaEngine-1.16.6.jar:$CLASSPATH" '

Comment: Be aware that the system scope is deprecated and will be removed in the future. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html describes how to work with jars that don't exist in external repositories like Maven Central

Comment: I had seen this method but I don't really like it since I would have to repeat the installation to be able to use it on other machines

Comment: anyway, I just tried to do this but the result is the same